# Error in `[.data.frame`(., df1$Sample.ID, !df1$Sample.ID %in% df2$Sample.ID) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the samples ids that only exist in a dataframe. Initially, I am removing the duplicates and then pipe the results to get the samples ids that are not common to both dataframes.

I am using the above code:

```
df1 %>% distinct(Sample.ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  df1$Sample.ID[!df1$Sample.ID %in% df2$Sample.ID]
```

Then I read, and I tried:

```
df1 %>% distinct(Sample.ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  df1$Sample.ID[!df1$Sample.ID %in% df2$Sample.ID,]
```

My example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Sample.ID=c("H22","H33","H44", "H55","H22","H33","H44", "H55),
                  sample.no=c(1,3,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(Sample.ID=c("H33","H55"), pane=c(5,6))
```

I am use the package "tidyverse"

I expect to get;

```
Sample.ID
H22
H44
```

It works if I don't pipe but I have to assign them to new dataframes but that is not ideal.

Comment: Since it looks like you are using `dplyr`, it would be better to just use `df %>% anti_join(df2)`

Comment: @MrFlick, I was editing my question but you got first LOL.

Comment: @MrFlick. I doesn't work I changed the code to `df1 %>% distinct(Sample.ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% df1(anti_join(df2, by=Sample.ID))` and I get the error **Error in df1(., anti_join(df2, by = Sample.ID)) : 
  could not find function "df1"**

Comment: You don't need the `distinct` part. You literally only need `df %>% anti_join(df2)`. It works fine on the sample data you provided.

Comment: @MrFlick. Sorry, I didn't realise that I misrepresented my dataframes. One them have duplicates, I have corrected the question so it can be clearer.

Comment: Then you can do `df %>% distinct(Sample.ID) %>% anti_join(df2)`

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks, you answered my question. However, I cannot see where I can mark it as answered.